# How to eliminate hits from elasticsearch response?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have my query performing only aggregations. But the response which I get after querying shows hits. I just need the total hits number and the aggregation results. Is there any way by which I can do this in elasticsearch?.

Comment: `{"size" : 0,query{},aggs{}}` will give you only aggregations. Refer to [ES Doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_executing_aggregations.html)

Comment: @ChintanShah25 Why is this a comment? Looks like an answer to me.